# Side effects of breaking the relation between __eq__ and __hash__ in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, hash, equals-operator

According to the [Python 3 documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__), objects that compare equal should have the same hash value. However, it is not uncommon to have two different mutable objects that at a given time can be compared equal, and you may still want to use them as different keys in a dictionary, for example.

In such cases, it is ok to reimplement the `__eq__()` and `__hash__()` methods to allow this distinction, and thus breaking the `a==b → hash(a)==hash(b)` assumption? Or it is better to define a new `"equals()"` method with the same semantics? What are the possible side effects of breaking this relation?

Comment: It sounds like you want your objects to be considered *equivalent*, which (mathematically) is not the same as *equal*. Without knowing more details about your presumed use case, I would say create a new method.

Comment: If your objects are mutable, then you shouldn't be defining a `__hash__` method at all.

Comment: In general mutable objects make for poor dict keys for this exact reason.

Comment: The documentation is a little vague about mutability and hashing, but I think it is OK if the mutable portions of an object don't affect `__eq__` or `__hash__`.